# Simple R Shiny App to select documents that have a certain word

Tags: r, shiny

1. Problem: the idea is to create an R Shiny App to select documents, from a directory, that have a word(s) of interest. So, let's say for example, I'm interested in selecting all documents that contain the word "Chevy", and then creating a list of all the document names that meet this requierement to display as final result.
2. What have I tried?
   At the momnet, I am only working with PDF files. I wrote some simple code that works but when turning this code into Shiny code it returns nothing. First, here is the code I wrote:

   ```
   directory <- "/Users/R/pdf_files"
   # Search for documents with specified keyword.
   want <- keyword_directory(directory, keyword = c('chevy'), 
                      ignore_case = TRUE,recursive = TRUE,
                      split_pdf = TRUE, full_names = TRUE)
   print(unique(want[2]))

   # The above returned this:
   pdf_name
   1 joes_garage_Boston.pdf
   3 dakota_race_track_sale.pdf
   ```

This result is ok, for now, but as I previously mentioned when taking this code into Shiny it returns nothing. Let me show you what I mean in the next section.

3. Show Shiny code:

Here is the Shiny code. When I run the code below it returns the following: 
    [1] pdf_name
    <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

```
# Shiny Code:
ui <- fluidPage(
            textInput(inputId="directory",label="Enter path to documents"),
            textInput(inputId="words",label="Enter keywords"),
            actionButton(inputId="go",label="Search for documents"),
            hr(),
            verbatimTextOutput("res")
)

server <- function(input,output){
      docs <- eventReactive(input$go,{ 
                                      keyword_directory(input$directory, 
                                                  keyword = c(input$words), 
                                                  ignore_case = TRUE,
                                                  recursive = TRUE,
                                                  split_pdf = TRUE, 
                                                  full_names = TRUE)
                            })
      output$res <- renderPrint({
                                print(unique(docs()[2]))
                                })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

So, I'm not sure why this is happening. I am using the same folder and same keyword. Another thing to note is that when I run the App it returns no error at all. I am expecting a list like the one I showed in step2 above.

Any recommendations, alternative solutions, tips, etc... are all welcome. I am new to Shiny and would like to find the best and most effective solution to this problem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Where is your shiny app saved? I bet it has to do with your directory location of the app in comparison to the mapping you type in for the files

Comment: Hi @Kevin, I save my Shiny App in "/Users/R/". Does this answer your question Please let me know.

Comment: So when your shiny app looks for the file, it's going to look in "/Users/R/Users/R/pdf_files". Is this where your pdf's are stored? Try just typing in "/pdf_files" in the directory of the shiny app and seeing if that produces anything

Comment: Hi @Kevin, my pdf files are store in: "/Users/R/pdf_files". As you suggested, I entered "/pdf_files" and I still get the same message: [1] pdf_name <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
Here is how I made the App work:
I entered the path to the documents like this: 
    ~/R/pdf_files
Lastly, I entered the keyword like this:
chevy

No quotation marks.

Thank you very much for reading my post!